# Let $x,y≠0$ with $x+y-2xy=0$, such that $4^x=9^y=a$. Then, what is the value of $a$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

> **Task:** Let $x,y≠0$ with $x+y-2xy=0$, such that $4^x=9^y=a$. Then, what is the value of $a$?

My attempts.

Let, $x=\log_2m,\, y=\log_3n$ then using $\frac 1x+\frac 1y=2$ gives,

$$\begin{align}m^2=n^2&=a\\
\log_{m^2}2^2+\log_{n^2}3^2=\log_a{36}&=2\\ a&=6.\end{align}$$

**Teacher's original solution:**

$$\frac 1x+\frac 1y=2$$

$$4=a^{\frac 1x}, 9=a^{\frac 1y}$$

$$36=a^{\frac 1x+\frac 1y}=a^2\\
a=6.$$

Backround:

Sometimes I try to help neighbor children in their lessons, which they are stuck in, only at the level of precalculus mathematics that I know.
I learned that the teacher rejected the solution I taught and said it was an unnecessary, long and fuzzy solution.

I accept that the teacher's solution is very nice and more elegant. I wanted to ask the question here for to get the mathematical opinion.

Is everything okay with my attempts? Maybe I missed some important points?

Comment: Not everyone thinks the same. Some people will prefer your method, some will prefer your teacher's method. Some may even prefer their own methods.